# make the a tag take all width and height of its container

Tags: html, css

I need the `<a>` tag placed inside the `<th>` tag to take all width of the `th`

```
<table>
    <th style="width:200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid black">
        <a style="border: 1px solid black; width:100%; height: 100%">
        </a>
    </th>
</table>
```

but it didn't work.

I can't change the markup structure, only apply styles to it, because of it was generated by UI-framework.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69redhuo/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```css
th {
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position:relative;
}
a {
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <th> <a></a>

    </th>
</table>
```

---

**EDIT**

Ok so basically this is what is happening. An element, by default, is given `position: static`. This is the default behaviour and the element is set to its current position in the flow.

> **static** This keyword lets the element use the normal behavior, that is
>   it is laid out in its current position in the flow.  The top, right,
>   bottom, left and z-index properties do not apply.

By changing it to `position: relative`, I cannot explain it better than Mozilla:

> **relative** This keyword lays out all elements as though the element were not
>   positioned, and then adjust the element's position, without changing
>   layout (and thus leaving a gap for the element where it would have
>   been had it not been positioned).

Changing the parent element to `position: relative` then allows us to change the child element to `position: absolute` (and for it to work)

`position:absolute` means that the element will not take up space in the document. It is positioned according to its closest positioned ancestor (in this case, the parent)

> **absolute** Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a
>   specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor or to
>   the containing block. Absolutely positioned boxes can have margins,
>   they do not collapse with any other margins.

Gathered from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Perfect, your answer is satisfying my needs best. But can;t you give a little explanation of why it's working?

Comment: In particualrly, why wasn't it working when I didn't set position: relative to th?

Comment: You're welcome :) Mozilla's Developer Network (MDN) has a lot of well-document information. Read through it sometime, you'll probably learn something new. I know I do all the time! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Answer (score 3):

Add `display: block;` to the tag: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69redhuo/3/)